# Where does Visual Studio store file properties?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio there are some file properties such as Build Action, Custom Tool, and whether the file is Content etc. Where are these properties stored? For instance, if I modify the build action for a file, how does Visual Studio remember the new value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the solution (.sln) and project (.csproj) files.

This [msdn project properties link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7f8bfy4.aspx) might also help.

Comment: Interestingly, for this question I was looking at the Custom Tool property which appears as <Generator> in the .csproj file but is modified through the DTE with "CustomTool".

Answer (score 9):

In the .CSPROJ file, wich is stored as xml since Visual Studio 2005 I think. You can Right Click on a project, do "Unload", and then right click again and do "Edit xxx.csproj" and you will see the text directly. If you update it, you can again right click and do a "Reload".

Comment: good tip, and works in 2010 too. I normally just use notepad++ or whichever text editor is to hand.